# Not possible to install chilkat gem in ruby version 2.0.0p643

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails application I am using `chilkat` gem to access the server. My Ruby version is `2.0.0p643`. How can I install chilkat to my ruby version? I had tried `gem install chilkat200` but throwing the following error

> ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'chilkat200' (>= 0) in any repository
>   ERROR:  Possible alternatives: chilkat

when I tried `gem install chilkat` the following error throws

> ERROR:  Error installing chilkat:
>       chilkat requires Ruby version ~> 2.2.

Is there any way to install chilkat to Ruby version 2.0.0p643. I can't change my rails application to version 2.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 64-bit Linux should work:

```
wget https://www.chilkatsoft.com/download/9.5.0.54/chilkat-9.5.0-linux-x86_64-ruby-2.0.gem.tar.gz
tar xzf chilkat-9.5.0-linux-x86_64-ruby-2.0.gem.tar.gz
gem install chilkat-9.5.0.54-x86_64-linux.gem
```

for 32-bit Linux replace above url with `https://www.chilkatsoft.com/download/9.5.0.54/chilkat-9.5.0-linux-x86-ruby-2.0.gem.tar.gz`

Comment: I am using MacOs - 10.13.2 High Sierra, with ruby version 2.3.0 for my rails application. I am trying to install chilkat that supports my ruby version but unfortunately i am getting LoadError: cannot load such file -- chilkat Kindly advise